# DropDownList value not get properly?

Tags: jquery, html

Dropdown list value get it as like this [object] [object]

this is my Jquery

```
        $("#empID").change(function () {
            var empId = $(this).val();
        });
```

i get empid as [object] [object]

```
i appending values like this in button click through ajax call back 

        $("#btnClick").click(function () {

            debugger;
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                data: JSON.stringify({ seatId: "101" }),
                url: "/Home/SeatInformation1",
                contentType: "application/json",
                success: function (data) {
                    debugger;
                    var test = JSON.parse(data);
                    if (test.length == "1") {
                        $('#empID').append($('<option></option>').attr('value', test[0]).text(test[0].EMPID));
                        $('#empID').append($('<option></option>').attr('value', test[0]).text("E3385"));

                        $("#textname").val(test[0].UserName);
                        $("#textemail").val(test[0].EmailId);
                        $("#textrole").val(test[0].RoleId);
                        $("#textportno").val(test[0].SeatId);
                        $("#textmanager").val(test[0].ReportingManagerId);


                    }

                }

            });
        });
```

if i append values in change not able to get value i get it result as like [object] [object]  .. How can i get values ?

Answer (score 2):

You are assigning Employee object to `option` value instead of employee id. 
So put `test[0].EMPID` in value attribute instead of `test[0]`.

Make correction at below line in your ajax call :

```
$('#empID').append($('<option></option>').attr('value', test[0].EMPID).text(test[0].EMPID));
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this code, it works for me:

```
var json_obj;
$.ajax({
...
success: function (data) {

  json_obj = $.parseJSON(data);
  var output = '';

  for (var i in json_obj) {

    if (json_obj[i][4] == 1) {
      output += '<option value="' + json_obj[i][0] + '">' + json_obj[i][0] + '</option>'
    }
  }

  $('#empID').empty().append(output).multiselect('rebuild');
 }
});
```

Let me know if it worked.